# Showing data from REST API

Tags: rest, api, oauth-2.0

I have to fetch data from an API and show it in a HTML table. I am trying to manually test the API using Postman but it is showing the following error

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "keyword": "type",
            "dataPath": "",
            "schemaPath": "#/type",
            "params": {
                "type": "object"
            },
            "message": "should be object"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "schema": {
            "$ref": "xxxxxxx#/definitions/ban/links/0/schema"
        }
    }
}
```

It uses Oauth 2.0 and I'm trying to set the token in the URL as follows

```
https://api.xxxxxxxx.com/bans?Authorization=Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6ImRhOWRiMTU0ZDkwMjY5ZWIiLxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Are you sending a JSON object in the request? Have you set the Content-type header to "application/json"?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my problem. I was using the token in the headers and also in the url.